# mkdir - create a subdirectory with specific name

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, mkdir

After hours of searching here and Google, I decided to ask for help.
I want the code posted to create a subdirectory in directory `uploads`, named by the variable `$userDir`. It does not give any errors in `php error logs` but it also does not create the sub-directory.

**Code:**

```
    <?php

    $userDir = $_POST['user_dir'];
    $targetFolder = '/uploads';
    if (!file_exists($targetFolder.'/'.$userDir)) {
   mkdir($targetFolder.'/'.$userDir, 0700, true);  
}
   //* Some other code here
    ?>
```

Does anyone know why it does not create the folder?

Comment: error seems clear to me

Comment: I am glad you can see the error. :) Would you share it, please?

Comment: "Warning
This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.". Is this your case?

Comment: It was not my case, but thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then the folder may already exist - but not where you think it is.

Try replacing your mkdir line to:

```
if (!file_exists(getcwd().$targetFolder.'/'.$userDir)) {
   mkdir(getcwd().$targetFolder.'/'.$userDir, 0700, true);  
}
```

Correct your target path :

```
 $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetFolder.'/'.$userDir;
```

Comment: It gives me no error and it does not create the sub-folder.

Comment: It just puts the image in the main directory `uploads`.

Comment: you don't add the user directory to the target folder.

Comment: Amended my previous answer - check your paths

Comment: I made it. Indeed was creating a sub-directory, but not in `/uploads`. It created it where my configuration script was. I just modified your answer to: `if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetFolder.'/'.$userDir)) {
   mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetFolder.'/'.$userDir, 0700, true);  
}`